# postfix as relay - send to non local domain restrict by ip

Tags: postfix, relay

we are moving from an old symantec messaging gateway to a debian/postfix machine.

rules in symantec are these:

-from local domain to the same, accept from all then relay all to outlook.com server.

-from local to non-local domain, accept only from specific ip addresses then relay all outlook.com 365 server.

the part "relay all to outlook.com" is done but i can't understand how filter by ip for the second rule.

here my actual main.cf:

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
myorigin = /etc/mailname
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 3.6

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = xxx.yyy.it
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
mynetworks_style = subnet

relayhost = zzz.mail.protection.outlook.com]
mydestination =
```

thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible using the standard config. But straightforward if you split the relay only and local delivery across different hosts. I would strongly encourage you to use SASL authentication as a mechanism for validating clients rather than an arbitrary list of IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

### Restricting who can use the server for relay

You currently accept any message for any destination with your

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0
```

If you have an IP address `192.0.2.10` and a network `198.51.100.0/24` that should only be allowed to use this email gateway for relay, you would use:

```
mynetworks = 192.0.2.10/32 198.51.100.0/24
```

You could also use [SASL authentication](https://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) for access control.

### Relaying all mail for certain domains

Postfix has [`relay_domains`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relay_domains) to control...

> What destination domains (and subdomains thereof) this system will relay mail to. For details about how the `relay_domains` value is used, see the description of the [`permit_auth_destination`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#permit_auth_destination) and [`reject_unauth_destination`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unauth_destination) SMTP recipient restrictions.

Knowing this, you could use

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
    permit_auth_destination, 
    permit_mynetworks, 
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject
```

or

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
    permit_mynetworks, 
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination
```

with

```
relay_domains = example.com
relayhost = [example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com]
```

The `mynetworks` (and/or SASL authentication) configured previously prevents others from using this gateway for all destinations, but the `relay_domains` accepts any messages for the configured domains.

### Restricting sender domain

The old Symantec Messaging Gateway additionally restrict access per sender domain. In Postfix, this could be restricted on two different levels.

##### Envelope sender

The domains used in SMTP `MAIL FROM` ([RFC 5321, 4.1.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321.html#section-4.1.1.2)) command can be restricted using [`check_sender_access`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_sender_access) from [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions).

The restrictions from previous phases can be applied on later ones, so this can be applied within `smtpd_relay_restrictions` or `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`. Keeping in mind that...

> As of Postfix 2.10, relay permission rules are preferably implemented with `smtpd_relay_restrictions`, so that a permissive spam blocking policy under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` will no longer result in a permissive mail relay policy.

This would be added as, e.g.,

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
    check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

With `/etc/postfix/sender_access` containing

```
/@example.com$/  OK
//               REJECT  Relay allowed only from our domain.
```

##### Header sender

The sender address that the *mail user agent* (MUA) shows to the user is not the envelope sender, but a header from Internet Message Format  *Originator Field* `From` ([RFC 5322, 3.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.6.2)). As an email header it could be restricted using [`header_checks`](https://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html). The following configuration requires [Postfix PCRE Support](https://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html) that comes with Debian package [`postfix-pcre`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/postfix-pcre).

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Where the file contains:

```
if /^From:/
!/^From: .*@example\.com/ REJECT Relay allowed only from our domain.
endif
```

### Putting these together

Putting all the previous together it is possible to build a configuration that works similarly than the old setup with the Symantec Messaging Gateway. In `main.cf`:

```
mynetworks = 192.0.2.10/32 198.51.100.0/24
relay_domains = example.com
relayhost = [example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com]
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
    check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_access,
    permit_mynetworks, 
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject
```

This allows all messages meeting the following criteria and rejects the rest:

- the envelope sender is `*@example.com` AND
- the `From` header has `*@example.com` AND
- any of these:

  - the recipient is `*@example.com` OR
  - the client IP is either `192.0.2.10` OR
  - the client IP is in network `198.51.100.0/24`

The accepted messages are relayed to smart host `example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com`.

### Microsoft 365 considerations

By default, the `example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com` only accepts mail (from the Internet) *for* `example.com`. See [Set up connectors to route mail between Microsoft 365 or Office 365 and your own email servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/set-up-connectors-to-route-mail).

> **A connector from your own email server to Office 365**
>
> When this connector is set up, Microsoft 365 or Office 365 accepts messages from your organization's email server and send the messages to recipients on your behalf. This recipient could be a mailbox for your organization in Microsoft 365 or Office 365, or it could be a recipient on the internet. To complete this scenario, you'll also need to configure your email server to send email messages directly to Microsoft 365 or Office 365.

The [Part 2: Configure mail to flow from your email server to Microsoft 365 or Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/set-up-connectors-to-route-mail#part-2-configure-mail-to-flow-from-your-email-server-to-microsoft-365-or-office-365) has two options for authenticating your server:

> 6. Choose either of the two options between
>
>    - By verifying that the subject name on the certificate that the sending server uses to authenticate with Office 365 matches the domain entered in the text box below (recommended) and
>    - By verifying that the IP address of the sending server matches one of the following IP addresses, which belong exclusively to your organization.

This connector enables `example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com` to work as a *smart host* SMTP relay for your email gateway.

Comment: we would like to maintain the old config so: 
from our to our domain all can use the relay. 
from our to external domain only some ip can use the relay.

Comment: This limits the access based on the **recipient** domain: all relay to your domain is allowed per `relay_domains` and restricted to the limited IP addresses by `reject_unauth_destination`. If you want to further limit the sender domains, it is just one addition for the envelope sender and maybe another for the `From` header.

Comment: i don't think this is ok. we want that all sender ip addresses can write to relay and these all can write from our to our domain, but only a group of these ip can use the relay to write to external domain.

Comment: And that is what this does.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the sender address restrictions & a full example putting all these pieces together.